# Where can I find data sheets for a Sanyo Denki 103H5208-1241 Stepper Motor

Tags: stepper-motor, datasheet

I've acquired some Sanyo Denki 103H5208-1241 stepper motors and I can't find the data sheet for it for the life of me. I've spelunked their catalogs and such looking for them.

Where can I find them or can I safely use another stepper data sheet interchangeably?

Comment: Is this not it? http://db.sanyodenki.co.jp/stepping_e/two/pdf/2step_e_069-073.pdf

Comment: @a swandwich +1 1st google result searching for 'Sanyo Denki 103H5208'

Comment: There are three 103H5208 models listed in that sheet, none of which are the 1241. The models that are listed vary from 0.25-1A/Phase and 66-1.4 Ohm/Phase. The back-plate of this model indicates a resistance of 1.6 Ohm (it has that and 1.8 degrees per steps) which doesn't match any of those. That is the catalog I mentioned btw.

Comment: Looks like the best I can do is forum posts and experimenting to see. The accepted answer is good, but the overall lesson is, "if you want detailed specifications find the data sheet *before* you buy something. Thanks for the efforts on my behalf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a specific part number and don't get a good result with the full thing, start stripping off parts and see if that helps.  For instance, ATMEGA169PA-AU defines an exact part you can order, but searching for "ATMEGA169PA" or "ATMEGA169" probably would give more helpful results.

For your case, "103H5208-1241" seems to provide good results when searched, but "103H5208" does as well, many of them seeming to be whole catalogs or large sections thereof.

The reason for my example is because most of the additional letters tacked on simply indicate mechanical features or different grades, but the core part is still the same.  Your stepper motor might also differ in some mechanical aspects (threading, mounting, whatever), but even a different part with a similar part number should have closely related features, so you could glean something from that.

Comment: Thanks, that is good advice and I'm fairly sure I can trust the wiring diagrams from the other 103H5208 datasheets I've found. But I can't figure out what the maximum current rating is, I've found three supposed max current ratings in forums, ebay, and such. (I'd like the power curves and such as well, but a reliable max current would be enough.)

Comment: @Jagerkin, ["Sanyo Denki 103H5208-0842 or -1241 NEMA 17 1.8 deg 200 steps/rev when full-stepping 2.0 ohm motors, Current per Phase: 1.2A unipolar, 1A bipolar"](http://www.edaboard.com/thread194845.html#post816719)

Answer (score 1):

Sanyo Denki 
Type 103H5208-0842 or -1241

STEPPER MOTOR, 1.8 deg 200 steps/rev when full-stepping

PIN1 / RED = A 
PIN2 / BLUE= B 
PIN3 / YL = A- 
PIN4 / ORG = B- 
PIN5 / WHT = COMMON 
PIN6 / BLK = COMMON

Description 
1.6 or 2.0 ohm motors 
Current per Phase: 1.2A unipolar 1A bipolar 
External Depth: 39mm 
External Length / Height: 42mm 
External Width: 42mm 
Frame Size: 17 
Holding Torque: unipolar 42.48 oz/inch (0.3N-m) bipolar 55.23 oz/inch (.39N-m)

Comment: Reference citation, please